# Windows 7 - How do you disable error message pop-ups?

Tags: windows-7

I have a Windows 7 machine that is constantly running test scripts. Services will occasionally fail and throw an error dialogue that I won't be around to attend to. These stack up over time and I would prefer to disable them completely.

So far I've found instructions to disable the error reporting and solution searching functionality that is built in to the operating system but I still get an option to quit or restart the application. I would like it to simply fail silently.

Does anyone know how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to find it pretty hard to stop Windows (and the programs running on it) from throwing error dialogs, especially in an across-the-board kind of way.

Your best bet is to spend your time enhancing your scripts to include [exception (error) handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) of their own so that they can deal with those errors gracefully (and silently).

If it's always the same error dialog another (more hackish) option may be to come up with something that continually monitors for that specific dialog window and closes it for you.